# Data on average/typical retail markups

Tags: data-request, pricing, retail-economics

Can anybody provide a reliable source that gives data on retail markups? My end goal is to make a fairly high-level statement along the lines of "a typical retail markup (across all industries) is X%", or "the average markup in industry Y is X%", so fairly aggregated data would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the [Comp-Net database](http://www.comp-net.org/data/). It is a firm-level data for European countries. It includes a large range of variables, including mark-ups:

[image]

Check the [documentation](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/home/pdf/research/compnet/CompNet-database-user_guide-round4.pdf) for more details.

Many researchers have also used the [Amadeus database](https://www.bvdinfo.com/en-us/our-products/company-information/international-products/amadeus), also for Europe. A nice summary about it is [here](http://www.nber.org/data/international-finance/Sebnem.pdf).

For the US, take a look at [this paper](http://www.janeeckhout.com/wp-content/uploads/RMP.pdf). The authors use three different sources of markups: Compustat, NBER Census of Manufacturing, and IRS (Inland Revenue Service). The first two are micro-data whereas the latter is aggregate at industry level.